# how to clear or empty datagrid after saving data

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

i already try

```
    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');
```

in the description it's describe "reload the current page data" but it didn't work

first i have page like this

http://www.indojpg.com/images/994Untitled.jpg

after i add some data it becomes like this

http://www.indojpg.com/images/431Untitled2.jpg

and then after i save the data the field should became empty again like first picture

how can i do this?

anyone can help me?

thank you

Comment: I am not able to see those images can you upload it here itself? or can u upload it to picsurge!?

Answer (score 1):

If only you want  clear or empty datagrid, You can try this:

```
 $('#dg').datagrid('loadData',[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$('#dg').treegrid('loadData', {"total":0,"rows":[]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear/empty the contents by using `.html('');`

So  `$('#dg').html('');` will work in your case for clearing the datagrid

Comment: sory i'm a newbie but where should i put it? i use these for saving action <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-save" plain="true" onclick="javascript:$('#dg').edatagrid('saveRow'),$.messager.alert('Info','Data Saved!','info')">Save</a>

Comment: you can have it in place where you want to clear your datagrid

Comment: it didn't work..the trigger should be after clicking the save button the page become empty